# How to start with an R-tree index in IBM Informix

Tags: sql, informix, r-tree

I have an assignment in which I need to build R-tree indexes on a table and query them.
But I am not getting proper tutorial or guide which specifically deals with R-tree in IBM Informix 
and querying an R-tree.
I tried to Google but without much success.
Can anyone can provide me with a good startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what Google search terms you used, but I get to a good selection of information using:

- site:ibm.com informix r-tree index

Variations on this search theme is how I usually search for IBM Informix Dynamic Server documentation on the IBM web site - when I'm not accessing the PDF manuals which I keep downloaded.

Specifically, the section [Using R-Tree Indexes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.spatial.doc/sii-rtree-38586.htm) (Google indexes an older version of IDS; this URL is to the IDS 11.50 Info Center), seems to cover the questions you have.  This is from the Spatial DataBlade guide.  You could also use the [R-Tree Index User's Guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rtree.doc/rtree.htm) as a source of information.  See, for example, [When does the Optimizer use an R-tree Index](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rtree.doc/sii-using-41704.htm).

If this does not sufficiently point you in the correct direction, you'd better update the question and explain what you don't understand, with cross-references to the documentation where you don't understand what it is saying.